iTerm Preferences Access without Menu
My menubar icon, menu and dock icon have all been removed. How can I access general Preferences? I can only reach the Session Settings.

Does a restart help? If this gets closed, have a look at [tour] and edit in some details like what build of macOS is running and how often this happens.

A user space reboot should clear out all the things and let you log in again without rebooting the OS (which also should help short term) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390819/5472
